# How can I prevent execution of endpoint if required field is not entered? OpenApi Swagger C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, openapi

I have an endpoint which has a required field define as such within a document filter:

```
        myOperation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter()
        {
            Name = "itemId",
            In = ParameterLocation.Path,
            Description = "Item Id.",
            Required = true
        });
```

Within swagger I can see that the parameter has the tag required next to it, but I am still able to click execute. This then throws a JavaScript error saying the required parameter is not provided.

How can I make it so the execute button cannot be used until the parameters are met?

Comment: Swagger/OpenAPI is a means of documenting your APIs, it does not provide functional constraints.

Comment: I understand that. In other scenarios required parameters prevent the execution button in swagger. I am trying to understand that

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem I have specified that the value cannot be empty as well as the format I wanted.

```
            AllowEmptyValue = false,
            Schema = new OpenApiSchema
            {
                Type = "string",
                Format = "uuid"
            }
```